# Image links does not appear on Firefox

Tags: html, css, image, firefox, cross-browser

I have several images that are nested inside anchor tags. They appear perfectly on Chrome and IE. Even IE 7 ! 
But on Firefox 18 the images don't appear at all. Here's my code :

```
<div id="follow-wrapper">
    <p>Follow Us</p>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img id="facebook-img"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img id="twitter-img"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img id="googleplus-img"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img id="linkedin-img"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img id="youtube-img"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img id="rss-img"/></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>


#follow-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 15px;
    width:230px;
}

#follow-wrapper p {
    float:left;
    font-family:'Arial', Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color : #20417f;
}

#follow-wrapper ul {
    float:left;
    list-style: none;    
}

#follow-wrapper ul li {
    display: inline;    
    margin-left:8px;  
}


#follow-wrapper ul li a img {
    border: none;
}

#follow-wrapper ul li img {
    background-image: url('../img/follow.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;   
    border-radius: 2px;
}

#facebook-img{
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}

#twitter-img {
    background-position: 0px -26px;
}

#googleplus-img{
    background-position: 0px -52px;
}

#linkedin-img{
    background-position: 0px -78px;
}

#youtube-img{
    background-position: 0px -104px;
}

#rss-img{
    background-position: 0px -130px;
}
```

Here's the result on Chrome :
[image]

And here's for FF :
[image]

I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: have you tested by replacing `img` tags with `div` tags?

Comment: I've never seen anyone try to set a background image on an img tag before. I'm not surpised it's acting strangely. Why are you doing that and not just using the src attribute of the img tag to display the image normally?

Comment: Look, you should use the `img` with an `src` attribute. It is not optional, so don't be surprised if you don't get the result you're dreaming of. In most cases it is not fortunate to mix up `img` with the sprite technique. Also, those little images are actually links, so what about simply styling the `a` elements and not having any `img`s at all?

Comment: @bažmegakapa I've tried that. But no images appear in all browsers

Comment: @RafaelAdel `display: inline-block`

Comment: I would suggest you use `<img src="facebook.png" alt="facebook" />`
And so on within the anchor tag itself so that you get the effect that you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/img.html

"**SRC** is mandatory."
edit: to clarify - **`src`** is a mandatory attribute of the `img` element.

Guess FF is the only browser playing by the rules. But the point is, your code is not valid.

You aren't saving any code using this: `<a href=""><img id...></a>` vs `<a href="" id=""></a>`. If anything, you're writing more.

Answer (score 1):

Two choices:

1. Cut up your sprite and use the img tag as it was meant to be used with an src of an individual image.
2. Use your sprite but apply it to the anchor tags instead of img tags.